# How can I get results from 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that searches for users in the db. I have two input fields so that I can search for e.g. city and house number. What I want is that if I type e.g. London in the city field and the number 20 it returns the record with London AND 20 in it. I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. I did enough research on Google but still didn't find the answer.

Here is my code:

```
if($_GET['search'] != ''){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klant_id LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR             voornaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR achternaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR email LIKE '%"        .$search."%' OR plaats LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search."%'ORDER BY       klant_id DESC");


$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klant_id LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR voornaam   LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR achternaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR email LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR   plaats LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%'ORDER BY klant_id DESC");
$i = 0;

}
```

What I need is something that will give the proper $result where those two search values ($search and $search2) are combined. Thus allowing me to search much easier.

Hope that i phrased my question well enough for you to understand me and I hope that you can help me!

Comment: Do you have to match the input values with all the fields?

Comment: Do you want just one record from the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the following logic -

```
if($_GET['search'] != ''){
$search = $_GET['search'];
$where[] = "( klant_id LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR  voornaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR achternaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR email LIKE '%"        .$search."%' OR plaats LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' ) ";
}
if($_GET['search2'] != ''){
$search2 = $_GET['search2'];
$where[] = " ( klant_id LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR voornaam   LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR achternaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR email LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR   plaats LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%') ";
}
$query_where = (is_array($where))?" WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where):""; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant ".$query_where." ORDER BY klant_id DESC");
```

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant ".$query_where." ORDER BY klant_id DESC"); that gives an error for mysql argument not valid.. What do i do wrong?

Comment: Sorry - one first brace was missing there - if($_GET['search2'] != ''){
$search2 = $_GET['search2'];
$where[] = " (

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to run 2 queries and get 1 result set you should be looking at a UNION query

Answer (score 1):

The words "UNION" (for only distinct values) or "UNION ALL" (to allow repeats) between your two queries will join them into one results table.

But when it comes to searches, I highly recommend against using %word%.  It'll slow your search down tremendously once you have a lot of data because SQL will iterate through the length of entire strings to find anything that contains the word in question.

Comment: What is your suggestion then?

Comment: He's only making you aware of a very valid point, using'%blah%' means no indexes will be used, the query will do a full table scan.  So if you have 1 million records it will examine every single one.

You need to decide if the performance hit is worth it.

Comment: In your example, it doesn't seem like dropping the first % would be that problematic.  For example, if a person types in "20" because they want to get house number 20, do you want them to see "120" "4120" and "1520141"?  Dropping that first wildcard will make your database much more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` clause
For example: *First Query..* UNION *Second Query..*
:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use another OR operator with brackets:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        klant 
    WHERE 
        (klant_id LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR 
        voornaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR 
        achternaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR 
        email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
        plaats LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR 
        bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search."%') 
    OR 
        (klant_id LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR 
        voornaam   LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR 
        achternaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR 
        email LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR 
        plaats LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR 
        bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%') 
    GROUP BY 
        klant_id
    ORDER BY
        klant_id DESC");
```

But UNION might look cleaner as the other answers suggest.

Added group by to prevent the same result from displaying multiple times.

Comment: Union and OR don't work, I still wont get the good result. Maybe I should reprashe: If I got the city london and have three house numbers there, and I search for London & 20 I want to get only London 20, not all three. And of course I have more 'cities' so any other city with number 20 is also not allowed

Comment: Then you could add a group by clause to make only one entry per found result

Comment: Or change the single `OR` in Nightwolf's query to `AND`.

Comment: @ypercube: It all depends on which set of results you would like to receive, but I can get duplicates from just the first query, that is why I suggested a group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET['search'] != ''){

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klant_id LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR voornaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR achternaam LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR plaats LIKE '%" .$search."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search."%'ORDER BY klant_id DESC";

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klant_id LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR voornaam   LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR achternaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR email LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR plaats LIKE '%" .$search2."%' OR bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%" .$search2."%'ORDER BY klant_id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query1 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query2;
$i = 0;

}
```